# RMarkdown Yacas Latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, yacas

I'm trying to do computer algebra in R using Ryacas and RMarkdown.

Here's a quick example.

````
```{r}
library(Ryacas)
x = Sym("x")
y = Sym("y")
x0 = Sym("x0")
y0 = Sym("y0")
x1 = Sym("x1")
y1 = Sym("y1")
yacas("TeXForm(Solve( (y - y0) / (x - x0) == (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0), y) )")
```
````

How can I get text from the R output parsed as LaTeX?

Edit:

results = `asis` did work, but the output is wrapped in single rather that double dollar signs. Only the double dollar sign expressions seem to parse correctly (try knitting the below).

$$\left( y =  - \left( \frac{ - y_{0}}{x - x_{0}}  - \frac{y_{1} - y_{0}}{x_{1} - x_{0}} \right)  \left( x - x_{0}\right) \right) $$

$\left( y =  - \left( \frac{ - y_{0}}{x - x_{0}}  - \frac{y_{1} - y_{0}}{x_{1} - x_{0}} \right)  \left( x - x_{0}\right) \right) $

Comment: results = 'asis' maybe

Comment: That seemed to work, but see edit above

Comment: If you simply need to change single into double `$` enclosure, why not replace your expression with `paste0('$', yacas(…), '$')`? Granted, it’s not pretty but this could (should!) of course be wrapped inside a function

Comment: Yup. See solution above.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks baptiste and Konrad Rudolph.

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
library(Ryacas)
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)


print.Expr = function (x, ...) {
  answer = yacas(x, ...)
  answer$YacasForm %<>% stri_replace_all_fixed("$", "$$") %>% stri_sub(2, -3)
  print(answer)
}

print.Sym = function (x, ...) {
  answer = yacas(unclass(x), ...)
  answer$YacasForm %<>% stri_replace_all_fixed("$", "$$")  %>% stri_sub(2, -3)
  print(answer)
}

x = Sym("x")
y = Sym("y")

TeXForm(x + y)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Another option (which I think is far preferable):

````
```{python3, results = "asis"}
from sympy import *
def LaTeX(math):
  return("$$" + str(math) + "$$")
x, y = symbols("x_0, y_0")
print(LaTeX(x + y))
```
````